# How can I mark an answer if I don't know which is correct?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, answers

I have this question [How can I put minerals back into distilled or reverse osmosis water?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/4924/how-can-i-put-minerals-back-into-distilled-or-reverse-osmosis-water)

The trouble is I don't know who is correct. I would normally go off vote count, but no one has over 1 vote. The only real way (that I see) for me to know the correct answer is to experiment and brew different batches and see who is right. Experimenting to find the answer would take time more time then is usual for accepting an answer.

How do I select an answer in this circumstance?

Comment: great and difficult question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer -- *don't!*

Not every question has to have an accepted answer, it is by no means required. We view accepts as more of a social convention closing the loop between asker and answerer than a perfect "this is the absolute correct answer in all circumstances" blessing.

Simply upvote both answers if they were helpful, and that should be sufficient -- perhaps 6 months or a year from now new answers or clarifications will emerge over time on the question.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Cheers to you Jeff.  I have certainly found a few cases of newbie question accepts a newbie answer, and the answer is wrong or misleading.

Comment: Wish this was in a faq. Good distinction.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jeff has hit it. There are what are considered to be popular conventional answers that may indeed be incorrect in absolute. But they may not make a huge difference in the long run. I read some of what is accepted as a chemist and shudder and have had what I know is true from chemistry negatively voted because it ran counter to old/accepted information. But for example on your original mineral question, the answers may have portions that are perfectly true but other portions that are problematic. Upvote them if they are helpful in your making a decision for action to answer a problem. If there are contradictions, do some research. You'll feel better about it and may be able to go back and help correct the understanding of the erroneous poster.